# How to use both Navigation Rule and f:ajax

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, navigation, facelets

Here's my scenario: I'd like to update a page via Ajax in some cases, in other cases, execute a navigation rule. My use case is a login form. I'd like them to receive an error message via ajax if their uname/password fails, but navigate to a new page if it succeeds.

Has anyone done this using JSF2.0 f:ajax apis? I'm not really interested in solutions that go outside standard facelets, jsf2.0, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not different from when doing it without ajax. Just return the next view ID as `String` the usual way via `<h:commandXxx action>` (and thus **not** `<f:ajax listener>`).

So, just

```html
<h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{bean.login}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
</h:commandButton>
```

with

```
public String login() {
    // ...

    return "nextpage";
}
```

will work as good as without `<f:ajax>`. It'll just go to `nextpage.xhtml`.

#### See also:

- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener)
- [JSF f:ajax listener vs commandButton action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222687/jsf-fajax-listener-vs-commandbutton-action/)

Comment: Neat! if you want to stay on the 'current page', you just return "" I discovered. Wow, this was not difficult at all!

Comment: You're welcome. When you want to navigate back to the same view, rather return `null` (or `void` if possible) instead of empty string so that the view (and the view scoped bean, if any) will be reused instead of recreated.