# JSF f:ajax listener vs commandButton action

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I'm curious what is the difference between these two ways of executing ajax calls:

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.action}">
   <f:ajax execute="@form" render="component"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

and

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit">
   <f:ajax listener="#{bean.action}" execute="@form" render="component"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

It appears that people use the first way more often, but the second seems to work just fine as well...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first way allows for navigation by returning a `String` outcome and the second not. The second way won't invoke anything if the client has JS disabled, while the first way [gracefully degrades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript#Degrading_gracefully). Indeed, the first way is used more often.

The second way is the only way in components which doesn't have an `action` attribute, such as `<h:selectOneMenu>` and so on.